# Not able to run .sh in shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to run shell script in php. Although the shell_exec() is working 
(I had tried to run `$result = shell_exec('ls')` and it work great), 
`$result = shell_exec('sh /where/the/file/is/test.sh')` seems not able to run. It's get not output in $result.

Note: test.sh is rwxrwxrwx

Comment: What does your `test.sh` do? I had a simple `echo "Hello World"` in mine and it worked perfectly with `shell_exec('sh ./test.sh');`.

Comment: I have `echo 'hi'`

Comment: Does it run ok when executed from console under `www-data` user? Also try `shell_exec('sh /.../test.sh 2>&1')` to see if the execution failed with error.

Comment: Oh! The $result shows that `sh: 0: Can't open /where/the/file/is/test.sh`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Put the .sh file in any directory in the $PATH env-var for the user-account doing the shell_exec();

Comment: @Yu-JieZheng Make sure the web server's user (`shell_exec('whoami')`) has `+x` on all directories leading up to `/where/the/file/is/test.sh`. If the user e.g. doesn't have execute permission on `/where/the/file`, then it will be unable to run or access `/where/the/file/is/test.sh` no matter what the permissions on `test.sh` are. You can use `sudo su webserveruser` (as found by `whoami`) to get a shell as the user for testing, or use `shell_exec('ls /where/the/file 2>&1')` to help determine which directory is missing or inaccessible.

Comment: It works after changed the file permission. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

shell_exec('./test.sh');

Or 
shell_exec('. ./test.sh');

Or 
shell_exec(' . test.sh');

Some version do not support